# do i need to validate select/option in drupal 7 form

Tags: forms, validation, drupal

I am creating my first drupal form and i am wondering if its needed to validate the select options? here is the form element

```
  $form['page1']['color']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title'=>t('Select Transmission'),
    '#empty_value' => '',
    '#options' => $color_options,
    '#required'=>TRUE,
    '#default_value' => !empty($form_state['values']['color']) ? $form_state['values']['color'] : '',
  );
```

so since drupal have the hidden fields for security can i trust that this form is always sent unaltered from my website?

thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to validate the select options. Drupal will take care of it for you. If a user tries to alter the value of a option (that is not one of a key or your $color_options array) with Firebug (or whatever), he will get the message "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." from Drupal.

Furthermore, you don't need to set a value from "$form_state" for the "#default_value" key. Just put one of the key of the "$color_options" for instance or don't use the key at all if you don't need a default value.